# YouTube Data API v3 on Android - how to distinguish limited accounts

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-authentication

I'm working on a simple wrapper library which will allow quickly implement upload video to YouTube and I've faced with problem: there are several "types" of accounts user can select - normal account with full Google functionality, service account (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors, search for words "youtubeSignupRequired") and some business accounts with restricted access to some Google services. Of course it's my own classification and it's not rely on official docs.
So, at some point I'm requesting user to select an account

```
private void selectAccountToLogin(Activity activity){
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE}, true, "", null, null, null);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
}
```

These lines just creates a dialog to choose account and all is ok right now. Next I want to get token for selected account:

```
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, account, OAUTH_SCOPE);
```

Important - I've received tokens for all "types" of accounts (and I think it's normally due to common authentication procedure in Google services). Next I want to upload my video to YouTube and here is magic comes:

1) For my personal gmail account all going ok - video uploaded successfully.
2) For business account (with no access to YouTube) I've received 401

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
 {
   "code" : 401,
   "errors" : [ {
     "domain" : "global",
     "location" : "Authorization",
     "locationType" : "header",
     "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
     "reason" : "authError"
    } ],
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

Why I'm getting 401 instead of 403 or else? (It's more rhetorical question) But all is not so bad at this point:
3) for service account I've also received 401

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
 {
   "code" : 401,
   "errors" : [ {
     "domain" : "youtube.header",
     "location" : "Authorization",
     "locationType" : "header",
     "message" : "Unauthorized",
     "reason" : "youtubeSignupRequired"
   } ],
   "message" : "Unauthorized"
 }
```

So for two different reasons I've got same 401. Of course I can distinguish these situations by domain and header params in json response but as for me it's ugly and inaccurate approach.
Maybe somebody already faced with this problem and solve it more accurate way? All I want - get accurate info about situation and represent it to user.

Comment: have you found any solution on this? If yes, please share some link with me. +1 to your question.

Comment: @VVB Unfortunately, no. As soon as this wasn't a main feature of our app we omitted this issue.